# Upgrading Microsoft.Fast.Components.FluentUI 1.6.0 to 2.1.4 Blazor WebAssembly does not load CSS or JS

Tags: c#, blazor, blazor-webassembly, fluent-ui

Looking at the NuGet for [Microsoft.Fast.Components.FluentUI 2.14](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Fast.Components.FluentUI/2.1.4#readme-body-tab) they state the following:

> When upgrading from an earlier version If you are upgrading from an
> earlier version of the library, please see the [what's new](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Fast.Components.FluentUI/2.1.4) for
> information on (breaking) changes.

The link does not give any more documentation though and only links to the same NuGet.

I have been looking at the latest integration documentation here and I still receive errors:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/fluent-ui/web-components/integrations/blazor

When starting the project I get stuck on `Loading...`

[image]

It looks like this in Console:

```
GET https://localhost:44397/_content/Microsoft.Fast.Components.FluentUI/css/reboot.css net::ERR_ABORTED 404
DeveloperDrivenThreatModeling.Client.styles.css:1          GET https://localhost:44397/_content/Microsoft.Fast.Components.FluentUI/Microsoft.Fast.Components.FluentUI.bundle.scp.css net::ERR_ABORTED 404
DevTools failed to load source map: Could not load content for https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.umd.js.map: HTTP error: status code 404, net::ERR_HTTP_RESPONSE_CODE_FAILURE
blazor.webassembly.js:1          GET https://localhost:44397/_content/Microsoft.Fast.Components.FluentUI/Microsoft.Fast.Components.FluentUI.lib.module.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404
(anonymous) @ blazor.webassembly.js:1
(anonymous) @ blazor.webassembly.js:1
importInitializersAsync @ blazor.webassembly.js:1
(anonymous) @ blazor.webassembly.js:1
Vt @ blazor.webassembly.js:1
await in Vt (async)
(anonymous) @ blazor.webassembly.js:1
(anonymous) @ blazor.webassembly.js:1
blazor.webassembly.js:1 TypeError: Failed to fetch dynamically imported module: https://localhost:44397/_content/Microsoft.Fast.Components.FluentUI/Microsoft.Fast.Components.FluentUI.lib.module.js
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The documentation could be better for this. Looking at the projects [Github](https://github.com/microsoft/fluentui-blazor) I found [WHATSNEW.md](https://github.com/microsoft/fluentui-blazor/blob/main/WHATSNEW.md)

> An issue has surfaced in hosted Blazor projects with version 2.1 and
> higher. The Client project does not work correctly unless the package
> is also added to the Server project (without any further changes to
> the Server's .csproj file). We are working together with the AS.NET
> Core team to solve this. See [dotnet/aspnetcore#47135](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/47135)

Adding `Microsoft.Fast.Components.FluentUI` to my server project as well solved the issue.

Now the project loaded correctly.

Including `reboot.css` caused [MatBlazor](https://www.matblazor.com/) MatTable to have very small text:

I therefore only included the variables like this:

```
<link href="_content/Microsoft.Fast.Components.FluentUI/css/variables.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

When this was done I only had this error left:

```
blazor.webassembly.js:1 crit: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Rendering.WebAssemblyRenderer[100]
      Unhandled exception rendering component: The requested icon (Delete, Size16, Regular) is not available in the collection
System.ArgumentException: The requested icon (Delete, Size16, Regular) is not available in the collection
   at Microsoft.Fast.Components.FluentUI.FluentIcon.OnParametersSet() in /_/src/Microsoft.Fast.Components.FluentUI/Components/Icon/FluentIcon.cs:line 92
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.ComponentBase.CallOnParametersSetAsync()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.ComponentBase.RunInitAndSetParametersAsync()
```

[WHATSNEW.md](https://github.com/microsoft/fluentui-blazor/blob/main/WHATSNEW.md) had a solution for this as well. Add `PropertyGroup` to client AND server `.csproj`. Even though documentation says `without any further changes to the Server's .csproj file` this is not true. It will not load icons unless this is done.

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <!-- 
        The icon component is part of the library. By default, NO icons (static assets) will be included when publishing the project. 
 
        Setting the property 'PublishFluentIconAssets' to false (default), or leaving the property out completely, will disable publishing of the 
        icon static assets (with exception of the icons that are being used by the library itself). 

        Setting the property 'PublishFluentIconAssets' to 'true' will enable publishing of the icon static assets. You can limit what icon assets get 
        published by specifying a set of icon sizes and a set of variants in the '<FluentIconSizes>' and '<FluentIconVariants>' properties respectively.

        To determine what icons will be published, the specified options for sizes and variants are combined. Specifying sizes '10' and '16' and 
        variants 'Filled' and 'Regular' means all '10/Filled', all '10/Regular', all '16/Filled' and all '16/Regular' icons assets will be published. 
        It is not possible to specify multiple individual combinations like '10/Filled' and '16/Regular' in the same set. 

        When no icon size set is specified in the '<FluentIconSizes>' property, ALL sizes will be included*  
        When no icon variant set is specified in the '<FluentIconVariants>' property, ALL variants will be included*  
        * when publishing of icon assets is enabled 
    -->
    <PublishFluentIconAssets>true</PublishFluentIconAssets>

    <!-- 
        Specify (at least) one or more sizes from the following options (separated by ','):
        10,12,16,20,24,28,32,48 
        Leave out the property to have all sizes included.
    -->
    <FluentIconSizes>10,12,16,20,24,28,32,48</FluentIconSizes>

    <!-- 
        Specify (at least) one or more variants from the following options (separated by ','):
        Filled,Regular 
        Leave out the property to have all variants included.
    -->
    <FluentIconVariants>Filled,Regular</FluentIconVariants>

    <!-- 
        The emoji component is part of the library. By default, NO emojis (static assets) will be included when publishing the project. 
 
        Setting the property 'PublishFluentEmoji' to false (default), or leaving the property out completely, will disable publishing of the emoji static assets. 

        Setting the property 'PublishFluentEmojiAssets' to 'true' will enable publishing of the emoji static assets. You can limit what emoji assets get 
        published by specifying a set of emoji groups and a set of emoji styles in the '<FluentEmojiGroups>' and '<FluentEmojiStyles>' properties respectively.

        To determine what emojis will be published, the specified options for sizes and variants are combined. Specifying emoji groups 'Activities' and 'Flags' 
        and emoji styles 'Color' and 'Flat' means all 'Activities/Color', all 'Activities/Flat', all 'Flags/Color' and all 'Flags/Flat' emoji assets will be published.

        It is not possible to specify multiple individual combinations like 'Activities/Color' and 'Flags/Flat' in the same published set

        When no emoji group set is specified in the '<FluentEmojiGroups>' property, ALL groups will be included*  
        When no emoji variant set is specified in the '<FluentEmojiStyles>' property, ALL styles will be included*  
        * when publishing of emoji assets is enabled 
    -->
    <PublishFluentEmojiAssets>true</PublishFluentEmojiAssets>

    <!-- 
        Specify (at least) one or more groups from the following options (separated by ','):
        Activities,Animals_Nature,Flags,Food_Drink,Objects,People_Body,Smileys_Emotion,Symbols,Travel_Places 
        Leave out the property to have all groups included.
    -->
    <FluentEmojiGroups>Activities,Animals_Nature,Flags,Food_Drink,Objects,People_Body,Smileys_Emotion,Symbols,Travel_Places</FluentEmojiGroups>

    <!-- 
        Specify (at least) one or more styles from the following options (separated by ','): 
        Color,Flat,HighContrast
        Leave out the property to have all styles included.
    -->
    <FluentEmojiStyles>Color,Flat,HighContrast</FluentEmojiStyles>
</PropertyGroup>
```

Then modify client `Program.cs`:

Remove:

```
builder.Services.AddFluentUIComponents();
```

Add:

```
LibraryConfiguration config = new(ConfigurationGenerator.GetIconConfiguration(), ConfigurationGenerator.GetEmojiConfiguration());
builder.Services.AddFluentUIComponents(config);
```

Now I could start to adapt my code to the new syntax. The classes I had to modify most was [FluentIcon](https://brave-cliff-0c0c93310.azurestaticapps.net/Icon) and [FluentDataGrid](https://brave-cliff-0c0c93310.azurestaticapps.net/DataGrid)

For `FluentIcon` syntax changed from this:

```
<FluentIcon Name=@FluentIcons.Delete Slot="start" Size=IconSize.Size16 Filled=true UseAccentColor=false />
```

To this as an example:

```
<FluentIcon Name=@FluentIcons.Delete Slot="start" Size=IconSize.Size16 Variant=IconVariant.Filled Color="@Color.Fill" />
```

FluentDataGrid changed a lot by removing `ColumnDefinition`, `RowItemTemplate` and `FluentDataGridRow`.

Another thing to note:

```
<link href="{PROJECT_NAME}.styles.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

Should be the Blazor WebAssembly client project name so something like this:

```
<link href="YourProjectName.Client.styles.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```